# Perl Object to XML Using XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I'm attempting to use the XML::Simple CPAN module to convert output from our database into a simple XML structure. The problem is that the output being returned isn't what I was hoping for no matter what options I attempt to pass to XML::Simple.

The database table we're trying to output is just a bunch of items with the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

Here is the Perl code we're currently using:

```
my $SQL = qq| select * from items |;
my $sth = main::DatabaseQuery($SQL);

my $items;
my $count = 0;
while(my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    $items->[$count] = $item;
    $count++;
}

require XML::Simple;
my $xs = XML::Simple->new(ForceArray => 1, KeepRoot => 1);
my $xml = $xs->XMLout($ref);
```

This outputs the following XML:

```
<anon id="10000" name="Item 1" manufacturer="Manufacturer 1" added="2009-01-01" /> 
<anon id="10001" name="Item 2" manufacturer="Manufacturer 2" added="2009-01-01" /> 
<anon id="10002" name="Item 3" manufacturer="Manufacturer 3" added="2009-01-01" />
```

I instead want it output as follows:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>10000</id> 
        <name>Item 1</name> 
        <manufacturer>Manufacturer 1</manufacturer> 
        <added>2009-01-01</added> 
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>10001</id> 
        <name>Item 2</name> 
        <manufacturer>Manufacturer 2</manufacturer> 
        <added>2009-01-01</added> 
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>10002</id> 
        <name>Item 3</name> 
        <manufacturer>Manufacturer 3</manufacturer> 
        <added>2009-01-01</added> 
    </item>
</items>
```

I'm sure there is some minor thing I'm overlooking so please let me know how I can change our current implementation to produce our desired XML output. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
my $SQL = qq| select * from items |;
my $sth = main::DatabaseQuery($SQL);

my $items = [];
while(my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    push @$items, $item;
}

use XML::Simple;
my $xs = XML::Simple->new(ForceArray => 1, KeepRoot => 1, NoAttr => 1);
my $xml = $xs->XMLout( { items => { item => $items } } );
```

Note that I changed it to use push instead of counting and assigning to the last array index and also initialized items so you don't get `<item></item>` when there are no data rows.

Comment: Almost works but the code you provided doesn't nest each item under individual <item></item> tags and instead each item is nested in it's own <items></items> tag. I would like all items be nested under a single <items></items>. Any ideas how to update your suggested implementation to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like we both noticed this at the same time. Thanks for updating and for the quick response. Works perfectly!

Comment: @Russel C.: thanks, I'd fixed it before you commented (it had had `XMLout( { items => $items } )`)